# Converting dataframe column data to matrix using R

Tags: r, analytics, igraph, bayesian-networks

I have data in dataframe in following format

[image]

And i want to convert this data into a matrix like this, so that i can generate a graph out of it using R

[image]

Please advice how can i do this. Also if there are any packages available to generate a graph

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to convert to matrix, we can use existing data with `igraph` package, see example:

```
library(igraph)

# convert to igraph object and plot
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df1)
plot(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can do this using `base R` by first converting the columns to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements in both columns, then just do a `table`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, factor, levels = un1)
m1 <- table(df1[2:1])
class(m1) <- "matrix"
names(dimnames(m1)) <- NULL
m1
#             angle traingle rightangle similarangle pythogoreous end
#angle            0        0          0            0            0   0
#traingle         1        0          0            0            0   0
#rightangle       0        1          0            0            0   0
#similarangle     0        1          1            0            0   0
#pythogoreous     0        0          0            1            0   0
#end              0        0          0            0            1   0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(children.startnode = c("angle", "traingle", "traingle", 
"rightangle", "similarangle", "pythogoreous"), children.endnode = c("traingle", 
"rightangle", "similarangle", "similarangle", "pythogoreous", 
"end")), .Names = c("children.startnode", "children.endnode"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L), class = "data.frame")
```